# I would like to mask URL using php

Tags: php, apache

Please check following details

Suppose I have series of URLs like:

```
http://www.example.com/abcd1.html 
http://www.example.com/abcd2.html
```

Now what I want is, when some body try to access the URL

particular abcd1.html page should display but in browser address bar it should look like

```
http://www.example.com/abcd1
http://www.example.com/abcd2
```

I am using php as scripting and Apache web server.  is not static, I get the file name from database.

Comment: Show us [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Anything you had try?

Answer (score 0):

Try a router such as [this one](http://toroweb.org/), for example.

You can then route `/something.html` to `/something` or `/any/path/you/want`.